# how will I get data between Two dates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am unable to retrieve my data from the database. I have tried everything like between clause and AND (&) operator but i m not be able to find the solution. 
Basically i m working on daily expense manager project where i want to retrieve the data between two selected dates by the user and than income and expense data will be retrieved and the balance will be shown as per the range of dates selected. Please Someone help me out. 
This is how i Created the table.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" 
        ( "+ id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          "+Amount+" INTEGER ,
          "+ date + " TEXT ,
          " +incomecategory+" TEXT, 
          " +paymentmethod+ " TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(query);

    String query2="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME2+" 
        (" + id2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
         " +Amount2+" INTEGER ,
         " + date + " TEXT ,
         " +expensecategory+" TEXT , 
         " +paymentmethod2+ " TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(query2);
}
```

This is how i inserted into incometable

```
public void insertIntoIncome(int name,String category,String 
incomedate,String pm1){
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(Amount,name);
    values.put(date,incomedate);
    values.put(incomecategory,category);
    values.put(paymentmethod,pm1);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}
```

This function will show the income data retrieve from the table but i m facing the problem in retrieving the data.

```
public String getIncomeDataByWeek(Date startdate,Date enddate){
    String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    String result="";
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Date incomedate=null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast()==false){
        try {
            incomedate=df.parse(cursor.getString(2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if((incomedate.after(startdate))&&(incomedate.before(enddate))){
            result+="("+cursor.getString(0)+") "+cursor.getString(1)+" : 
            "+cursor.getString(3)+" - " + cursor.getString(2)+" : " + 
            cursor.getString(4)+"'";
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the date in YYYY-MM-DD format as string in Database.

Then try executing this query :

```
select * from mytable where `date` >= '2018-01-01' and `date` <= '2018-03-25'
```